# Use git to track changes to repo very often

Tags: git, cron, productivity

I write a lot of org-mode notes in several files in a git repo. I want to be able to use `git log -p` to support two types of queries:

1. See what I wrote on a given date, or a given range of dates.
2. Find when I wrote a given keyword.

This is already supported by `git log -p` if I commit every day. However, I need the commit messages as a sort of diary, committing infrequently, and I want to keep it that way. Thus, I want a parallel version of the git repository, just for searching.

**How to implement this?** I probably need `cron`, a way to have two git histories on the same repo, and also some way to have exactly one commit each day in the history.

As noted in the comments, one can `rsync` the repo contents to another branch and use `git-worktree`, but I don't really understand how to do this.

(If this is a horrifying example of the X-Y problem, please comment on that, so I can ask a broader question.)

Comment: That sort-of sounds like you want to maintain two independent branches and maybe commit with the "plumbing" commands, rather than with "porcelain". These generally don't affect the state of the user-friendly git interface, so you could keep your dairy workflow uninterrupted while cron does its daily job behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks! Could you elaborate on "two independent branches", because I don't see how to cleanly commit to another branch with unrelated history? I guess that's where the plumbing comes in.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Normally when you change branch with `git checkout`, it affects contents of the working directory. That's the point of the command. But with plumbing you can 1. create a tree object for the current contents of the working directory, 2. create a commit based on that tree and pointing at your daily branch's tip as its parent, 3. update the daily branch to point at that commit.

Comment: Understanding git repos' structure helps a lot. [This book](https://github.com/pluralsight/git-internals-pdf/releases) may be helpful. Alternatively you can [add a 2nd working directory](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree), sync its contents daily (`rsync` etc.) and maintain the 2nd branch there.